# Hmmlearn AIC and BIC computed with what variables in the model?

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

In following the reference example in the documentation, I implemented the same on sequence data for a model I am working on.

My issue lies in the fact that I don't know which parameters are being used for each iteration when the n_component variable increases. The documentation mentions no method for extracting this information and other comments on AIC and BIC state the most informative variable will be added to the model and the score recomputed. I need to know which values it is using in each iteration to determine the variable combinations and the related improvements in the score/quality of the model.

[Example from documentation showing the AIC and BIC computation](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_gaussian_model_selection.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-gaussian-model-selection-py)